# How to determine lenth of csv field in column and return all over a certain length

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to determine the length of all of the cells in a specific column and return all the cells over 40 characters. I then want the otion to just know which are over the limit or to be able to edit the cells to be under 40 characters and insert them back into their original spot.

This is an example of the file I have:

```
Name,Geo Location,Default
DRE EXT Pair Video,,
DRE United Kingdom EXT LON Extrane lo.EXT RD01,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom EXT LON Extrane lo.EXT RD02,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom LON lab dyna test,United Kingdom,
DRE United StatesCPT Corp Point Link_Pair Video,United States,
DRE United Kingdom SDD SASD-D TRAIL01 to RD01,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom SDD SASD-D TRAIL01 to RD02,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom SDD SASD-D TRAIL02 to RD01,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom SDD SASD-D TRAIL02 to RD02,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom SDD SASD-D TRAIL01 to TRAIL02,United Kingdom,
DRE United Kingdom SDD SASD-D RD01 to RD02,United Kingdom,
DRE United States MDR SASD-D XC Xplay to,United States,
DRE Hong Kong (China) Hongkong HKOuter RD01 HKInter,"Hong Kong, Hong Kong",
DRE United Kingdom LON Sq lab dynam test,United Kingdom,
DRE United States USTHA SPS Thalberg usthamd mdf01,United States,
DRE Hong Kong (China)DRE SASD-D Citi EXT,Hong Kong,
SASD-D United States USPHXCAP VRF RD02,United States,
```

I want to check all the fields in the name column to see if they are 40 characters or longer and, like I said above, have the option to just view them or edit them and insert them back into the file.

I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around how to accomplish this. If I could get at least the fields to print that are 40 characters or more that would be a good starting point.

The code below is what I have to start with:

```
import csv
import collections

lthlst=[]

with open('file1.csv','rb') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    od = collections.OrderedDict(r)

    for line1 in od:
        lng=len(line1[1])
        lthlst.append(lng)
        for i in lthlst:
            if i >= 40:

print lthlst
```

I am getting an error from this `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks,

B0T

Comment: So fix the error - *view* the line indicated by the exception message/trace, then reason about why it is generated. Then work on the actual problem. An error like this is not a task, nor a problem. Just a bug with the code.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks, I'll play around with what you suggested. I just want to output it to a file and then be able to edit the file manually and input what I changed into the original file at the original line/row, if that makes sense.

Comment: @user2246674 It was for the `od = collections.OrderedDict(r)` line in the code. I did look u what it meant, but didn't really get anywhere other examples were different from my code.

Comment: The OrderedDict constructor it takes in a list of key/value *pairs*. This is not what is in r here - r is probably a list of *triplets* due to the trailing comma on the lines - and hence the exception. *Pairs* were expected, but something else was encountered.

Answer (score 1):

The OrderedDict constructor it takes in a list of key/value *pairs*. This is not what is in r here - r is a list of *triplets* due to the trailing comma on the lines - and hence the exception.

Normalize it first:

```
r = csv.reader(f)
list_of_pairs = [ (i[0], i[1]) for i in r ]  # ensure only pairs ..
od = collections.OrderedDict(list_of_pairs)  # .. to not break this
```

Now, you can get back to real problems! Remember, to focus on the *specific* problem - which I've identified above - as this primary post/question is too general about a task and has nothing to do with this coding bug.

Comment: This actually doesn't work for my specific problem. It turns out I need actual numbered lines.